# Uploading to a date subfolder within a Matrix

Tags: assets, upload, subfolder

I'm working on a site that will have lots of content. Our customer now asked to have their images upload into a different subfolder, by date.
I can get it done in a "normal" Assets field, but in a Matrix I get an error: `Could not resolve the subpath “{postDate|date("d-m-Y")}”`, with `postDate` being the name of the generated folder.
I did the exact same thing in a "regular" Assets field and that does its job as it should.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for:

```
{owner.postDate|date("d-m-Y")}
```

See the note about dynamic subfolders on an Assets field inside of Matrix here: https://craftcms.com/docs/assets-fields#dynamic-subfolder-paths

Comment: That's it! I thought it was something like that, but yesterday was a busy and tiring day, so my brains where quite fried at the end of the day and I couldn't get my mind wrapped around the problem :-). Thanks for the help!!